# Unable to connect to REST api with c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I have this code in my website which is just a button and i'm trying to do a POST request to this api called schooltime https://schooltimeapp.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/requirements-for-apps-using-the-schooltime-api. Currently i'm trying to post 2 values into the REST api but i am currently having some trouble as my `var = response` keeps giving me this error `System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.` Any Help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://school-time.co/app2/index.php/api/students/");

        var postData = "name=hello";
        postData += "&email =world@test.com";
        //add other attributes...

        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("ST-API-KEY", "StRest@123");
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing the content type to "
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: @Gaurav still no luck same error

Comment: can you please use Postman to make a post request and check if you can access the page?

Comment: Yes. Test with postman. Note if I use the example URL in the website I also get a 403 but I also get a response saying "Invalid API Key" (which is to be expected). What does your response say?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid after adding the API key to postman it says that it could not get any response

Comment: I think there is some issue with the API or you are missing something which is required by the API.

Comment: I think you should not expect from this example to work on the production environment. Just like @Nick.McDermaid wrote, example request also doesn't work in the runner on the schooltimeapp documentation page. I'm sure that if you try to send your request using mock server (or just using real authentication data), it will work fine.

Comment: @MarcinTopolewski Im using postman to try and do a post request with the correct header and data but it still says its unable to get any response. If i remove the api key then it will give me a error 403.

Comment: Have you tried using their mock server - https://private-anon-39b1436e74-schooltimeapp.apiary-mock.com/app2/index.php/api/students/ ? It could be their production server checks your domain, IP or other factors on top of the authorization header.